# Understanding what's wrong with my authorization header using Perl, HTTP, LWP

Tags: azure, rest, perl, storage

I have a piece of PHP code that creates a Blob storage PUT request to a container in my Azure storage account. After significant tinkering, I finally got the header right and all is good. Unfortunately, the app I want to use this in is written in Perl. So I thought it would be a relatively easy task to port it. It is proving more difficult than I had expected.

I've compared everything (well, obviously not everything or it would freaking work) between the PHP code and the Perl code, but continue to receive an authentication error related to the header.

The PHP script uses Curl to make the user agent request. I do not have that accessible as a direct replacement in my Perl installation. Not sure there's much I can do about that without a local install and C-compiler for Net::Curl. (Maybe I'm missing something there?)  As everything between the two versions (PHP and Perl) seems to match i.e. message, key, encoded/decoded versions of strings, hashed signatures (I hardcoded the date for validation between the two implementations), I'm at a loss as to what else to try. This is day 3 and I feel I'm probably spinning my wheels on a problem this group has already solved.

The PHP Code which work just fine:

```php
<?php

date_default_timezone_set ( 'GMT' );
$date = date ( "D, d M Y H:i:s T" );

$version = "2009-09-19";

$account_name = 'emiliolizardo';
$account_key = "uXwt+WJ14kkV6zDALOuiDCsJtqrGDMK7W5xtNhuXXUcsfP1HIC1s7IJ+PZS7dgyXPBufad46ncBSQQK5rNs6Qw==";
$container_name = 'containertest';

$blobname = "foobar.txt";
$fdata    = file_get_contents('testfile.txt');

$utfStr = "PUT"
        . "\n\n\n"
        . strlen($fdata)
        . "\n\n"
        . "text/plain; charset=UTF-8"
        . "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"
        . "x-ms-blob-type:BlockBlob"
        . "\n"
        . "x-ms-date:$date"
        . "\n"
        . "x-ms-version:$version"
        . "\n"
        . "/$account_name/$container_name/$blobname";

$utf8_encode_str = utf8_encode ( $utfStr );

echo "utfStr : " . $utfStr . "\n";
echo "utf8_encode_str:" . $utf8_encode_str . "\n";

$signature_str = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256',    $utf8_encode_str, base64_decode($account_key), true));

echo "signature_str:" . $signature_str . "\n";

  $header = array (
   "x-ms-blob-type: BlockBlob",
   "x-ms-date: " . $date,
   "x-ms-version: " . $version,
   "Authorization: SharedKey " . $account_name . ":" . $signature_str,
   "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8",
   "Content-Length: " . strlen($fdata),
   );

print_r($header);

$url="https://$account_name.blob.core.windows.net/$container_name/$blobname";
echo "url:" . $url . "\n";

# Check our variables
#echo "account_name: " . $account_name . "\n";
#echo "account_key : " . $account_key . "\n";
#echo "signature   : " . $signature_str . "\n";
#echo "url         : " . $url . "\n";
#var_dump($header);

# Execute curl commands to create container
$ch = curl_init ();

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT' );
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fdata);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, True );

$result = curl_exec ( $ch );
```

And the Perl code, which comes close, but is missing something:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use DateTime;
use DateTime::TimeZone;
use Data::Dumper;
use Encode qw(decode encode);
use MIME::Base64 qw( encode_base64 decode_base64 );
use Digest::SHA qw(hmac_sha256 hmac_sha256_base64);
use HTTP::Request;
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $account_name = "emiliolizardo";
my $account_key  = "uXwt+WJ14kkV6zDALOuiDCsJtqrGDMK7W5xtNhuXXUcsfP1HIC1s7IJ+PZS7dgyXPBufad46ncBSQQK5rNs6Qw==";
my $container    = 'containertest';

#my $file = 'YhJCUjrcEi0q.mp3';
my $file = 'testfile.txt';

# -----------------------------------------------------------
# --
# -----------------------------------------------------------
sub uploadblob {
        my ($fname, $accname, $acckey, $cont) = @_;

        my $date = `/bin/date -u +"%a, %d %b %Y %T GMT"`; chomp $date;
#       my $date = 'Mon, 01 Jul 2019 13:14:43 GMT';     # -- JUST FOR TESTING

#       my $version = "2018-03-28";
        my $version = "2009-09-19";                     # -- JUST FOR TESTING TO MIMIC PHP CODE

        my ($blobname, $ctype);
        for ($fname) {
                /\.mp3$/i and do { $ctype = 'audio/mpeg'; last; };
                /\.wav$/i and do { $ctype = 'audio/wav'; last; };
                /\.txt$/i and do { $ctype = 'text/plain'; last; };
                die "Failed to match an acceptable extension";
        }
        my $blobname = $fname;

        open FILE, "< $fname" or die "Can't open file $fname for read: $!";
        my $fdata = <FILE>;
        close FILE;

        my $fsize = -s $fname;

        my $str = qq{PUT\n\n\n$fsize\n\n$ctype; charset=UTF-8\n\n\n\n\n\n\nx-ms-blob-type:BlockBlob\nx-ms-date:$date\nx-ms-version:$version\n/$accname/$cont/$blobname};
print "utfStr : $str\n";

        my $message = encode("UTF-8", $str);
print "utf8_encode_str:$message\n";

        my $secret  = decode_base64($acckey);

        my $signature_str = encode_base64( hmac_sha256($message, $secret) );
        chomp $signature_str;
print "signature_str:$signature_str\n";

#       while(length($digest) %4) { $digest .= '='; }   # -- Is this necessary for the hmac_sha256 digest?

        my $header = [
                'x-ms-blob-type' => "BlockBlob",
                'x-ms-date' => $date,
                'x-ms-version' => $version,
                'Authorization' => "SharedKey $accname:$signature_str",
                'Content-Type' => "$ctype; charset=UTF-8",
                'Content-Length' => $fsize
        ];
        my $url = "https://$accname.blob.core.windows.net/$cont/$blobname";
print "url:$url\n";

        sendPut($header,$url,$fdata);
}


# -----------------------------------------------------------
# --
# -----------------------------------------------------------
sub sendPut {
        my ($header,$url,$data) = @_;
print "\n\nIn sendPut()\n\n\n==============================================\n\n\n";

        my $r = HTTP::Request->new('POST', $url, $header, $data);

        my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
        my $res = $ua->request($r);

        print "res: ", Dumper $res, "\n";
}

uploadblob($file, $account_name, $account_key, $container);
```

The error message gives me a hint of what *might* be the issue but I'm not sure how to correct it: content-length header was wrong, fixed. This seems to be an existing issue with LWP (or was in 2006 which was the reference I found).

Using Data::Dumper to look at the HTTP::Request object before I send it with LWP, it looks ok to me. Just like the PHP request object. At some point I will rewrite the old-school Perl code in PHP or Node.js or something current, but for the moment, I'd really like to get this working in Perl.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions. Apologies if I've breached any SO etiquette -still pretty new here.

Thanks - Andy

Here's the complete response from the UserAgent->request:

```
Content-Length header value was wrong, fixed at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/LWP/Protocol/http.pm line 189.
res: $VAR1 = bless( {
                 '_protocol' => 'HTTP/1.1',
                 '_content' => '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code><Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:62589eac-301e-00bd-3e1e-30c15e000000
Time:2019-07-01T15:04:08.0485043Z</Message><AuthenticationErrorDetail>The MAC signature found in the HTTP request \'PUUgk2meSoiB9o+inlYomIq96Bf13IdAQoIZ4BSu4sE=\' is not the same as any computed signature. Server used following string to sign: \'POST


26

text/plain; charset=UTF-8






x-ms-blob-type:BlockBlob
x-ms-date:Mon, 01 Jul 2019 15:04:07 GMT
x-ms-version:2009-09-19
/emiliolizardo/containertest/testfile.txt\'.</AuthenticationErrorDetail></Error>',
                 '_rc' => '403',
                 '_headers' => bless( {
                                        'client-response-num' => 1,
                                        'date' => 'Mon, 01 Jul 2019 15:04:07 GMT',
                                        'client-ssl-cert-issuer' => '/C=US/ST=Washington/L=Redmond/O=Microsoft Corporation/OU=Microsoft IT/CN=Microsoft IT TLS CA 4',
                                        'client-ssl-cipher' => 'ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384',
                                        'client-peer' => '52.239.177.68:443',
                                        'content-length' => '723',
                                        'client-date' => 'Mon, 01 Jul 2019 15:04:08 GMT',
                                        'client-ssl-warning' => 'Peer certificate not verified',
                                        'content-type' => 'application/xml',
                                        'x-ms-request-id' => '62589eac-301e-00bd-3e1e-30c15e000000',
                                        'client-ssl-cert-subject' => '/CN=*.blob.core.windows.net',
                                        'server' => 'Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0',
                                        'client-ssl-socket-class' => 'IO::Socket::SSL'
                                      }, 'HTTP::Headers' ),
                 '_msg' => 'Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.',
                 '_request' => bless( {
                                        '_content' => 'Test file for blob upload
',
                                        '_uri' => bless( do{\(my $o = 'https://emiliolizardo.blob.core.windows.net/containertest/testfile.txt')}, 'URI::https' ),
                                        '_headers' => bless( {
                                                               'user-agent' => 'libwww-perl/5.833',
                                                               'x-ms-date' => 'Mon, 01 Jul 2019 15:04:07 GMT',
                                                               'content-type' => 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8',
                                                               'x-ms-version' => '2009-09-19',
                                                               'x-ms-blob-type' => 'BlockBlob',
                                                               'content-length' => 28,
                                                               'authorization' => 'SharedKey emiliolizardo:PUUgk2meSoiB9o+inlYomIq96Bf13IdAQoIZ4BSu4sE='
                                                             }, 'HTTP::Headers' ),
                                        '_method' => 'POST',
                                        '_uri_canonical' => $VAR1->{'_request'}{'_uri'}
                                      }, 'HTTP::Request' )
               }, 'HTTP::Response' );
$VAR2 = '
';
```

Comment: `my $fdata = <FILE>;` will only read the first line of the file. `my $fdata = do { local $/; <FILE> };` will read the whole thing. You probably also want to [binmode](https://perldoc.pl/functions/binmode) the handle so there are no layer conversions of the possibly binary data (e.g. line endings on Windows).

Comment: You shouldn't need to specify Content-Length manually, as LWP should set it based on the content you provide.

Comment: Minor code style issues: you should `use warnings;`, you should use three-arg open, and you should use lexical filehandles not global barewords: `open my $fh, '<:raw', $fname or die ...; my $fdata = do { local $/; <$fh> };` (the `:raw` layer is equivalent to calling binmode later with no layers)

Comment: Or use `read_binary()` from [File::Slurper](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Slurper).

Comment: @Grinnz - thanks. This is a quick hack to see if I can get it working only. I used 'strict' to prevent the most egregious errors. It's clearly not the cleanest code. :-)  Thanks for the comments: <FILE> is only a single line of text, I'm aware. COntent-length is part of the signed hash so it has to match with LWP computes from the header (line 47 of the Perl code).  However... that did lead me to what's wrong...

Comment: One issue I see is that in your `sendPut()` method, you're sending `POST` as HTTP method instead of `PUT`. That will **certainly** cause the request to fail. Please change that to `PUT` and see if the request is successful.

Comment: @Gaurav Mantri - yup, that was one issue. Just saw it and corrected. Content length is the problem. For this file, LWP says 26, and I'm computing 28. If I hardcode the 26 in the signature (and use PUT in the HTTP::Request) , the code works. Not sure how to correct this programmatically.

Answer (score 2):

Resolved in comments. @Grinnz and @Guarav Mantri - you guys had it right.

1. I had a second line (a dot that I didn't see) in my testfile. So reading a single line from the file, but computing the entire filesize with -s was going to provide a mismatch. Now content-length is being computed correctly.
2. I blindly type 'POST' in the HTTP::Request-new() call when PUT was used in the signature hash. Oops.

Thanks guys. Not sure how to upvote two responses as both had portions of the answer.

Comment: It's fine as there's no clear question-answer here, just a debugging process. It's why I did not submit an answer.